# Conditional distribution of $X_1=S_1+T$ and $X_2=S_2+T$

Tags: distributions, self-study, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

$S_1, S_2$ and $T$ are independently and uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. What will be the conditional distribution $G(x_1|x_2)$?

I have no idea on how to proceed. Any help will be appreciated.

Edit-
I can calculate the distribution of $X_1$ and $X_2$. I don't know how to proceed beyond that.

Comment: Please detail the difficulties you face with solving this basic probability question. And add the `self-study` tag for else the question faces being closed.

Comment: I don't have much idea as to how to proceed. I just need to know the approach.

Comment: One often is well served by applying a definition: what definition(s) of conditional probability do you know?

Comment: I need to make sure that $X_2 \geq X_1$. Is there anything more I need to specify?

Comment: If you have never heard of conditional and joint distributions, you should read the literature about these concepts. Why are you interested in the conditional distribution of $X_1$ given $X_2$?

Comment: I'm solving a certain problem in auction theory, and there I've encountered this distribution. I've read a bit about distributions, but this one is beyond my scope of knowledge.

Comment: A very good answer is given over here: https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/27512/16340